# regex repeating pattern seperated by commas

Tags: regex

I have this regex that validates that a string is valid as a set of three parameters as shown below:

```
(?<set>(?<field>(.+))\s*\,\s*(?<Type>(.+))\s*\,\s*(?<value>(\?)))
```

That works for this string

```
FIELD1,INTEGER,?
```

How do expand the regex to check repeating sets such as

```
FIELD1,INTEGER,?,FIELD2,INTEGER,?,FIELD1,STRING,?
```

Comment: Wrap your current regex in parentheses and use `+!`?  e.g. `(current regex)+` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get rid of a couple of those groups (within your named capturing groups) you have to make the regex a bit more clear. Then add `?` to the `+`'s within your named capturing groups so that they are not greedy. An optional `,` and a quantifier to the whole complete set also needs to be added so that the group may be repeated multiple times as you describe.

```
                  1                   2                         3    4
                  v                   v                      vvvvvv  vv
(?<set>(?<field>.+?)\s*\,\s*(?<Type>.+?)\s*\,\s*(?<value>\?)(?:[,]*))+?
```

1. Removed your capturing group and added lazy quantifier: `(?<field>(.+))` --> `(?<field>.+?)`
2. Same as above but for type: `(?<Type>(.+))` --> `(?<Type>.+?)`
3. Added an optional non-capturing group: `(?:[,]*)` (you dont need the `[]` its just there for clearity)
4. The pattern may be repeated 1 or more times with a lazy quantifier: `+?`

See https://regex101.com/r/USM9lP/1 for a full example

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The website you referenced was the same site I use to test with. It's a great resource. At first when I cut/pasted your expression it only highlighted the first group. I followed your link and noticed that the /g option was flagged for you. I was unaware of that and it made allthe difference. Thanks

Comment: One last question, if I wanted the entire Expression to fail if all conditions were not met for all groupings how would I accomplish that ?

Comment: Figured it out. I added ^ and $